# Screen freeze with multiple sessions

Tags: jsf, websphere, eclipselink

I have a JSF application using Primefaces 5.3, EclipseLink JPA and EJB running on Websphere 9 with Fixpack 11. When there are around 10-12 concurrent sessions , screen freeze happens and the application becomes very slow and unresponsive.
NOTE : When the same application was run on Websphere 8.5 with OpenJPA , no issues were reported.
Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: A profiler could shed light on this. You could e.g. use VisualVM and view what the app is doing. If most of the CPU active time is spent by the garbage collector, you probably need to increase the Heap space. If not you'll have to get deeper into it. Generally debugging question are considered off topic on StackOverflow, so I voted to close this.

Comment: Try to generate some thread dumps when you have the 'freeze'. You will see what threads are doing, maybe that will give you some light on what the problem is.